# How do you validate a select box in React Final Form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'm trying React Final Form. How can I validate the user has selected a value in a "select" box and that it is not longer the initial value. I'm using a Field like this, then just adding options by mapping an array.

```
<Field
  flex="1 0 200px"
  name="project-busOrgId"
  component="select"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two options are [field-level validation](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/field-level-validation), where you specify a `validate` prop to `<Field/>` or [record-level validation](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/examples/record-level-validation), where you validate all the form values at once and return an object of errors. Up to you.